# jquery syntax or regex for selecting specific items

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

A number of HTML elements (p, a, span, etc.) in my page have a 'title' attribute. In order to call a method on such elements (that styles their titles), I can do the following:

```
$('[title]').method();
```

Now I need to **prevent this from being called for all DIVs** whose ID start with a specific string , say '*myDiv*'. 
I bet there is a special jquery selector syntax for doing that, but am just not able to get that.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: *"I bet there is a special jquery selector syntax..."* No need to bet. The *first* place you should go is the documentation that @FelixKling linked.

Comment: @amnotiam, what I was not clear was the EXACT syntax.

Comment: The documentation provides EXACT syntax for all supported selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$('[title]:not(div[id^="mydiv"])').method()
```

[Documentation Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

[Documentation :not() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

**update: you can also do it as**

```
$('[title]').not('div[id^="mydiv"])').method()
```

[Documentation .not( selector )](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: Thanks! This is the most accurate solution of all! NOTE that I was looking for all **DIVs** that do not start with a given string ID). I guess some others are correct, but they missed this point

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[title]:not([id^='myDiv'])").method();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the :not selector.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/